# OutlinedTextField click in compose with talkback

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect

OutlinedTextField(
    value = ...,
    onValueChange = { ... },
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        .also { interactionSource ->
            LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
                interactionSource.interactions.collect {
                    if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {
                        // works like onClick
                    }
                }
            }
        }
)
```

I am using OutlinedTextField, the problem is that with no talkback it works fine.
But when Talkback is enabled, it doesn't behave as a click.And Click not detected. How to solve this issue.

Tried to implement click functionality on OutlinedTextField, works with no talkback. But with talkback it doesn't.